apcupsd service running: still communication with UPS lost
I have purchased a new APC UPS which I want to connect with four Linux Debian clusters.
I asked similar question earlier here: My own post but the solution is not working now for a new UPS. I followed the suggestions by @Stephen Harris to connect my old UPS to Linux cluster using a USB cable. However, following the same approach does not work while configuring a completely new APC UPS against two Linux clusters. The APC UPS Model: SURTD3000XLIM(APC model) has one swrial com connector and one USB connector on the back of the UPS. Two cables were provided alongwith the UPS purchase- a)  RJ-45 to DB-9 communication cable (goes to the serial com conenctor of UPS) and also b) an USB-A to mini-USB cable connector. I used both the cables to connect to our two Linux clusters.
In case of a)- the imp part of /etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf file looks like :
UPSNAME LG27a
UPSCABLE ether
UPSTYPE net
DEVICE 128.40.177.201:3551

NETSERVER on
NISIP 127.0.0.1
NISPORT 3551

After saving this file, I stopped apcupsd service and started again.
When I do systemctl status apcupsd, I receive:

Still when I do apcaccess, I get (Status:Comm Lost !):
APC      : 001,018,0445
DATE     : 2024-11-08 15:10:43 +0000
HOSTNAME : hartree
VERSION  : 3.14.14 (31 May 2016) debian
UPSNAME  : LG27a
CABLE    : Ethernet Link
DRIVER   : NETWORK UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Net Slave
STARTTIME: 2024-11-08 15:10:21 +0000
STATUS   : COMMLOST
MBATTCHG : 5 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
NUMXFERS : 0
TONBATT  : 0 Seconds
CUMONBATT: 0 Seconds
XOFFBATT : N/A
STATFLAG : 0x05000100
END APC  : 2024-11-08 16:51:44 +0000

In case of b)- the imp part of /etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf file looks like :
UPSNAME LG27a
UPSCABLE usb
UPSTYPE usb
DEVICE

NETSERVER on
NISIP 0.0.0.0
NISPORT 3551

After saving this file, I stopped apcupsd service and started again.
On systemctl status apcupsd, I receive :

In case b) as well, I am getting error (Status:comm lost) when I do apcaccess:
APC      : 001,018,0439
DATE     : 2024-11-08 16:46:41 +0000
HOSTNAME : meitner
VERSION  : 3.14.14 (31 May 2016) debian
UPSNAME  : LG27a
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2024-11-08 14:28:27 +0000
STATUS   : COMMLOST
MBATTCHG : 8 Percent
MINTIMEL : 4 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
NUMXFERS : 0
TONBATT  : 0 Seconds
CUMONBATT: 0 Seconds
XOFFBATT : N/A
STATFLAG : 0x05000100
END APC  : 2024-11-08 16:46:41 +0000

I checked all possible help resources such as : help1, help2 etc. But, still I could not succeed in setting up the communication.
For, b)type connectivity, when I type lsusb, it does not detect the UPS unfortunately.
I am unable to decipher the error. Kindly help me in rectifying the issue.
Thanks.

Could someone from the community shed some light on this issue please?
